# python:exchangelib:RHEL 6: GLIBC_2.14 issues

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am building my python artifact on a `RHEL 7` machine as the company policy says so. When we deploy the artifact to `RHEL 6` machine as the project demands it. I am hitting the error as shown below. Any idea what can be done to prevent the issue? I have already gone through all the other links for the error and it says upgrade to `RHEL 7`. I do not have root access and cannot get it. Error below:

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (... /lib/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-x86_64-lin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not specific to exchangelib, or Python for that matter.

You are trying to run software that was compiled for RHEL 7 on a RHEL 6 machine. That is not guaranteed to work, and in this case it doesn't work because the `lxml` package is linked against a version of `libc` that doesn't exist on RHEL 6.

You need to compile your Python packages on the same RHEL version that you want to run them from.

Comment: cool thought so ... thank you for the confirmation ... these issues are best resolved with using the proper version.... agreed will take this up ....